# What would be a good API format for "NOT IN" clause?

Tags: api-design

I have a query API against my service, that looks like this (JSON-ish format):

```
{
   filter: {
             attribute1: [val11]
            ,attribute2: [val21, val22]
   }
}
```

means effectively, select data `WHERE attribute1 IN ("val11") AND attribute2 in ("val21", "val22")` in SQL-ish syntax.

I need to expand this API to be able to express `NOT IN` predicate, and I'm at a loss as to what a good way to do so would be.

The only thing I can possibly think of is to add a second "filter_not_in" key in the request API, that would work like "filter" key but produce `NOT IN` semantics; but it seems really klunky and hard to grasp.

The API syntax can be thought of as JSON as far as its expressiveness/capability

An ideal answer would reference some well accepted rules on API design, to show that it's "good".

Comment: if this belongs on Programmers.SE instead, please let me know.

Comment: Not sure it belongs here, but what about adding an optional "operator" parameter/flag to the filter, with a default of being an "in" filter.  Then you change it to being `NOT IN` when the operator parameter/flag is present and has the value that is not equal to the default value.

Comment: @jmoerdyk That doesn't work if he wants to filter attribute 1 `IN` and attribute 2 `NOT IN`. It also means he can't have an attribute named `operator`.