# What would be a good API format for “IS NOT SET” clause?

Tags: api-design

I have a query API against my service, that looks like this (JSON-ish format):

```
{
   filter: {
            ,attribute2: [val21, val22]
            ,attribute3: []
   }
}
```

means effectively, select data `WHERE attribute2 in ("val21", "val22") AND attribute3 IS NOT NULL` in SQL-ish syntax (meaning, the object being returned has attribute 3 set, but I really don't care what its value is. SQL isn't very good at expressing this of course, as my data is key-value store where a key may be "not set" at all instead of being null valued).

I need to expand this API to be able to express `IS NOT SET` predicate, and I'm at a loss as to what a good way to do so would be.

The only thing I can possibly think of is to add a special "**NOT_SET**" value in the request API, that would produce `NOT SET` semantics; but it seems really klunky and hard to grasp:

The API syntax can be thought of as JSON as far as its expressiveness/capability

An ideal answer would reference some well accepted rules on API design, to show that it's "good".

```
{
   filter: {
            ,attribute2: [val21, val22]
            ,attribute4: [__NOT_SET__]
   }
}
```

Comment: For this question and the prior one, are you locked into your current "JSONish" structure, or is that changeable? I'm not asking about changing away from "JSONish", but rather changing the shape of the "JSONish".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to move away from trying to use a key-value pair to represent a predicate phrase. You should have a lot more flexibility with a structure similar to:

```
{
    filters: [
      { attribute: "attribute2", verb: "IN", values: [val21, val22] },
      { attribute: "attribute2", verb: "NOT IN", values: [val21, val22] },
      { attribute: "attribute4", verb: "IS NOT SET" },
   ]
}
```

You'd want an enum of verbs, of course, and values would have to be optional. You can add more verbs later if you need them, and you're no longer putting quite so much pressure on the poor `:`. You can also provide to the client a list of supported verbs and how many values (if any) of what type they take, so the client can build the UI dynamically, if desired.

Of course, this is a breaking change, which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: I'm unsure if I can use this, but it's a pretty big improvement in API design; +1

Comment: @DVK I've been thinking about it some more. If you can't introduce a breaking change, I think the best you're going to get is `filters` (implicit IN), `unset_filters:[..]`, and `not_in_filters`, as you mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262890/what-would-be-a-good-api-format-for-not-in-clause. Hopefully somebody else proves me wrong. :-(

Comment: I actually bit the bullet and did one better: old "filters" stays as is, new "filters_enhanced" has a format similar to your answer, except just as with my original format, attribute name is a key in the map and not an attribute in the vector. On server side, I simply convert old filters into new-format enhanced filters with "IN" predicate.